# Can't construct polymer web component inside ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to use a custom Polymer (v3) component inside an Ionic (also v3) app.

The component works fine if i'm running with `ionic cordova run android`.

But when i try to run with a `--prod` flag, the project compiles and opens in my phone but it simply does not show the component.

The error shown in the chrome inspect tools is the following:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object contructor cannot be called as a function.`

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tsc-wrapper": "^2.0.0",
    "my-polymer-component": "^1.3.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "0.0.21",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried to add webcomponents to my index.html but still got no success.

Comment: Check what version of JavaScript you are compiling to. This sounds to me like it's compiling to ES5 which doesn't support classes. You might also try upgrading dependencies. There might be some tooling that doesn't correctly handle compiling custom elements.

Comment: Abraham is right this error can only happen when you transpile a wc down to es5.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by adding a custom-elements-es5-adapter.js polyfill from [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs)